# Given line separated blocks of text, how can I return each block which contains a specific keyword?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, grep

```
me$ cat file.txt

Filename: 1
Organization: Bus 1 => Port 1 => Subport 1 => Device 3
Classes: Interface Video
Drivers: usbhid

Filename: 2
Organization: Bus 1 => Port 1 => Subport 3 => Device 4
Classes: Audio 
Drivers: usb-audio uvc Video

Filename: 3
Organization: Bus 1 => Port 1 => Subport 4 => Device 5
Classes: Wireless Video
Drivers: uvc
```

How can I manipulate this to return the blocks which contain any given keyword?

For example: bash this --class "Video" would return:

```
Filename: 1
Organization: Bus 1 => Port 1 => Subport 1 => Device 3
Classes: Interface Video
Drivers: usbhid

Filename: 3
Organization: Bus 1 => Port 1 => Subport 4 => Device 5
Classes: Wireless Video
Drivers: uvc
```

Writing the script to sort the --class and --driver case would be trivial, just asking particularly about the text manipulation. I'm thinking along the lines of grep Class:*$input, taking the line number, and printing everything from a a newline prior to that through the next newline, but that would have more complications and probably isn't the most efficient way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get Classes...Video:

```
$ awk -v RS= '/Classes:[^\n]*Video/' file.txt
Filename: 1
Organization: Bus 1 => Port 1 => Subport 1 => Device 3
Classes: Interface Video
Drivers: usbhid
Filename: 3
Organization: Bus 1 => Port 1 => Subport 4 => Device 5
Classes: Wireless Video
Drivers: uvc
```

(I tested this with mawk and GNU awk and it should work with any POSIX awk [hat tip: ninjalj) but it may not be compatible with [very old versions](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html#uh-19) of awk.)

#### How it works

- `-v RS=`

  This sets the record separator to be an empty string which is generally interpreted as meaning paragraphs.
- `/Classes:[^\n]*Video/`

  This returns true if the record (paragraph) contains `Classes:`, followed by any number of any characters except newline, followed by `Video`.  In other words, it returns true if *a line* contains the string `Classes:` and later contains the string `Video`.   If this condition returns true, then awk performs the default action which is to print the record (paragraph).

Comment: Thanks! Could you explain what exactly the line is doing? I can sort of interpret it as a variable is being set to be checked.

Comment: @ksm18 I just added an explanation.  Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Paragraph mode is standardized in POSIX: _If RS is null, then records are separated by sequences consisting of a <newline> plus one or more blank lines, leading or trailing blank lines shall not result in empty records at the  beginning  or end of the input, and a <newline> shall always be a field separator, no matter what the value of FS is._

Comment: @ninjalj Thanks!  That is good to know.  I will add it to the answer.  In [Grymoire's tutorial](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html#uh-19), I found this _"You can set the "RS" variable to change AWK's definition of a "line". If you set it to an empty string, then AWK will read the entire file into memory."_ which led me to suspect that older awks might behave differently.

Comment: In V7 (http://plan9.bell-labs.com/7thEdMan/vol2/awk): _If the record separator is empty, an empty input line is taken as the record separator, and blanks, tabs and newlines are treated as field separators._ The actual behavior regarding fields is to always treat newlines as field separators, and also treat either FS, or blanks and tabs as field separators.