# How can I find each block which contains a given string

Tags: bash, awk, grep

I have a file with multiple paragraphs. I want to pull the just the paragraph.

I referenced this question

[Given line separated blocks of text, how can I return each block which contains a specific keyword?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34009199/given-line-separated-blocks-of-text-how-can-i-return-each-block-which-contains/34009337#34009337)

but the solution is not working for me.

Here is an example of my data

```
 * This is a block of text it goes on and on. This is a block of text it goes on and on. This is a block of text it goes on and on. This is a block of text it goes on and on. This is a block of text it goes on and on. This is a block of text it goes on and on. This is a block of text it goes on and on. This is a block of text it goes on and on. (STOP-String-023)

 * This is a block of text it goes on and on. This is a block of text it goes on and on. This is a block of text it goes on and on. This is a block of text it goes on and on. This is a block of text it goes on and on.  (Search-String-085)

Here is random text. Here is random text. 

 * This is a block of text it goes on and on. This is a block of text it goes on and on. This is a block of text it goes on and on. (Search-String-035)
Some text here
Some text here
```

I want to pull just the text from the beginning of the paragraph up to the `(Search-String...`  how do I do this?

```
awk -v RS= '/Search-String[^\n]/ text.txt
```

command does not work.

Comment: Which `Search-String`, `085` or `035`? Also, "pull the just the"?

Comment: I've done my best to edit your question to make more sense but I reached a dead end. People won't be inclined to help you if you're so lazy about constructing your question. And please don't expect to write useful software using "phrasebook programming".

Comment: I'm certain you're not [a Senior Consultant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8106362/masc-0047) anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -v RS= 'sub(/.*Search-String/,"")' text.txt
```

If that's not what you want then edit your question to clarify your requirements and provide the expected output to go with your posted sample input.